# Share PHP session with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I have a PHP app that renders HTML pages for a social media application that I'm creating. Then, JavaScript initializes and makes things interactive. The PHP side of things logs into a separate webservice with ***curl***.

Now, I can't figure out a way to share the session started in PHP with JavaScript, so when I make a AJAX request in JavaScript to the data server, its authenticated.

**Is there a way to share a PHP session with JavaScript? Or to share authentication initially created with PHP with JavaScript?**

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543 read this article , may you will get the idea what to do .

Comment: This link was very helpful! I think i'll look more into using tokens than sessions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it sounds like there is something wrong with your architecture. In my opinion, the web server itself, should be the only peer providing data to the client/browser. It's a two party conversation only.

When trying to hit a third-party server from the browser, you violate the browsers Same-Origin Policy, unless you specifically allow CORS by explicitly setting various request and response headers. - and you would only do so in very special situations.

The best solution might be to create proxy services at the web server, that can be hit directly (locally) by the browser. The web server can then (acting as controller) forward the data-request to the data server (model) and finally return the response to the browser (view).

Comment: By the way.. If you really want to, it **is** possible to send a PHP session cookie to a third-party origin from XHR using the right CORS configuration. Your webserver should set _Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true_ header, and your Javascript code should configure XHR: _withCredentials: true_.

Comment: With the current set up i have, I do believe this would be the best way to carry out things. However, I think i'm going to investigate the use of tokens, that way I wouldnt have to worry about a session. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can read out the session cookie set by PHP (SID I guess) through JavaScript containing the session ID. 
When you make a query, use

```
http://example.com/?sid=SessionID
```

Comment: This is not a link-only answer. There's no actual link.